# javascript separate child process

Tags: javascript

I'm opening windows in the browser using JavaScript in order to have multiple processes working on a large data set I have.

The problem I'm having is that the child windows seem to still be tied to the parent, and so they aren't truly separate threads.  I think this is the case because I see the button I clicked in the parent tab is 'stuck' in the pressed position, and only one of the child tabs seems to be saving any data back to my database.

I'm wondering if there's a way to disassociate/remove the child process from the parent so the child tabs are truly separate processes.

Inside a loop, I open a window for each process I want...

```
childWindow[p] = window.open('rangerCocoon.php','Launched Game '+p);
```

I then wait a few moments for the child pages to load by using a timeout.  I realize that's a bit hacky, but this software is just for my own personal use so that's fine.  (My other option would be to have the child tell the parent it's finished loading).

Then I set some data to and submit a form in the child page...

```
childWindow[p].document.getElementById('data').value = dataPacket;
childWindow[p].document.getElementById('launchForm').submit();
```

Then here I'm wanting to break the child free from the parent...

```
childWindow[p] = '';
```

The last line does not break it free though it seems, because I still see the problem I'm having.

Note: I have to have the reference `childWindow[p]` to the child window because I need to set the data in the form in the child window, and submit that form.  i.e. I cannot just do a `window.open` call without doing `childWindow[p] = window.open`

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: "in order to have multiple processes working on a large data set", why not to use WebWorkers (threads)?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not multi-threaded in its normal operation, so when you open a new window, you're not actually opening a new thread, as it's created in the context of the same thread you're using to create them. See http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/ for some techniques on how to simulate multiple threads on your web pages.

If you're using HTML5 on your process, you can try using Web Workers, which are 100% multi-threaded. See http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=x3NE_fx2KzW for a simple explanation on workers, its pros and cons.